# Error in coding on geolocation

Tags: javascript

what is wrong with this code? lines 2 and 7 apparently have errors? Thanks

```
var location = Appery ('input').val();
if (location == '') {
   alert ('Please enter a location.');
   return;
}
var map = Appery('map');
map.options['address'] = location;
map.refresh();
```

Comment: i tried this instead var location = Appery ('input').val();
if (location == ' ') {
   alert ('Please enter a location.');
   return;
}
var map = Appery('map');
map.options[''] = location;
map.refresh();

Comment: Instead of adding alternate code as a comment, edit your question to add it.  This will allow you to format it as code, making it easier to read.  Once you do, let us know what the result of the new code is.  Also, please tag your question with the language you are using.

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE.  This looks like JavaScript which is the tag you should probably use instead.  It would help if you mentioned exactly what the "errors" are.

Comment: ...and those errors would be?

Answer (score 1):

You cant use name `location` for your variable!

> The Window.location is read-only property, returns a Location object
>   with information about the current location of the document.

Change it to something different:

```
var appery_loc = Appery('input').val();
```